# CORS issue with CouchDB + credentials + origin wildcard

Tags: cors, ionic2, couchdb, jelastic

I am trying to move from Cloudant to Jelastic on flow.ch. I am getting CORS errors with pouchdb when testing locally (ionic serve).

**Is there any other configuration in Jelastic besides CouchDB I am missing?**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxx.flow.ch/xxx. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

1. I configured a CouchDB on Jelastic and activated CORS.
   [image]
   [image]
2. Normal access via CURL works. Replication from Cloudant to Jelastic worked as well.
3. I tried to use a Chrome extension to enable "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [couchdb docs say this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/http.html#cors/origins):

> You can’t set `origins = *` and `credentials = true` option at the same time

So if you want cross-origin requests with credentials to work with couchdb, you must set the `origins` value to an explicit list of allowed origins; for example:

```
[cors]
origins = http://localhost, https://localhost, http://couch.mydev.name:8080
```

Comment: Its not CouchDB specific..Its actually a specification for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials). So no server side system which has CORS setup would allow this