# How do I access a remote couchdb with CORS and basic authentication from any device?

Tags: cors, couchdb

I need to access a remote CouchDB hosted on [smileupps](https://www.smileupps.com). I am having trouble with CORS. How do I configure it to allow any device to post documents using [basic authentication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/server/authn.html)? I know I need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true`, but then what about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? I can't use `*` but I need to be able to connect to any device. On the client side I can't use any library, just ajax.

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742360/441757. couchdb intentionally provides no supported way to do what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your CouchDB installation needs to have CORS configured so that it puts out the correct headers to allow "ajax" requests to be allowed from your browser to your CouchDB server.

The CORS configuration instructions are in the [CouchDB documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/config/http.html#cors). In short:

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
credentials = true
origins = *
methods = GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
```

Easier still is the "Enable CORS" button in the CORS section of the CouchDB dashboard:

[image]

Comment: I can't have origins set to `*` when credentials are set to `true`. See "Credentialed requests and wildcards" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS